# Eliminate scroll-bars and fit embedded pdf into my jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, pdf

**What am i doing :**

I'am developing a pdf reader on my website and on my homepage i have a number of e-books cover photos rendered and when a user click on a particular e-book , a jquery ui dialog appears and i render the pdf using [pdfobject library](http://pdfobject.com/).

**What i achieved :**

On clicking the icon of e-book , iam able to render the pdf object in the dialog.

**The problem :**

The display looks very bad.There are scroll bars in the pdf embededd object as well as the jquery dialog has scroll bar (verical and horizontal).

**What i want :**

my jquery dialog has width = 600 and height = 500 , when i first open the dialog there should just be 1 vertical scroll bar , the first page of pdf should fit into the exactly my dialogs default dimensions (600 X 500) irrespective how much are its orignal dimensions.
If a pdf has only 1 page , there should be no scroll bars (unless the user clicks zoom-in)

**Javascript code :**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pdfPrompt" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        width:600,
        height:500,
        resizable : false
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#pdfPrompt" ).dialog( "open" );
            var myPDF = new PDFObject({ url: "sample.pdf" }).embed('renderer');

        return false;
    });
});
```

opener is just the id i give to icon, and pdfprompt is a simple `<div>`

Example :

[image: This is what is happening]

After trying out charlietfl's solution(jsFiddle) :[image]

Can you'll please help me to achieve this ,Thank you

Comment: examples show how to fit:  http://pdfobject.com/examples/styled.html

Comment: @charlietfl , thanks for the response i tired that , i gave the  pdfOpenParams: {
                    
                    view: "FitV",
                } but it still gives 2 scroll bars (vertical)and 1 horizontal scroll bar

Comment: my need to modify overflow css and make sure div is dimensioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential issue is that hidden elements have no dimensions. This causes problems for example with google maps being processed in a hidden div. The pdf viewer script likely needs to get the dimensions of the container.

Remove animation for `show` for this reason.

You may need to wait until dialog opens to place the pdf in dialog.

```
$( "#pdfPrompt" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
   open:function(){
        /* code here to render pdf*/
    },
    hide: "explode",     
    width:600,
    height:500,
    resizable : false
});
```

Comment: you did not write anything ahead of open , after hide:"explode" what should i do there ?

Comment: oops..is a typo...second `open` shouldn't be there..am fixing now

Comment: i tried your approach , but still not helping , i uploaded a pic of what is happening

Comment: works fine for me setting pdf before open or after  http://jsfiddle.net/kuu3g/1/   OR http://jsfiddle.net/kuu3g/

Comment: i copy pasted the code from jsfiddle to my local machine ,the jquery dialog doesnt show an scrollbar but the embedded object(pdf) still shows the horizontal and vertical scroll bar , uploaded an image for the same

Comment: is it different than what's in my demo? I don't see any new image

Comment: hmm i just uploaded the image @charlietfl , i have edited my post

Comment: not sure what to tell you...my demo has a very tiny bit of css and tiny bit of code. Should be easy to replicate. Perhaps we see different things in my demo... I am looking at it in Firefox

Comment: you are not getting any scroll bars at all in your demo ?

Comment: not in Firefox..havn't checked any other browsers...what are you using when you see scroll bars in my demo? I do see some greyed out scroll like items when it opens and assumed that was the pdf viewer. I do get scroll bars if I zoom the pdf...same as example on plugin site

Comment: perfect , that is what i want ! , just on zoom there should be a scroll , but otherwise , i dont want any scroll bars , none at , all , can you please somehow send me your entire code or something i really want what you have achieved

Comment: btw iam using chrome to see scroll bars in your demo

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the google docs viewer which automatically resizes the viewed pdf ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/DhCCX/))

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you for the response , but 1. is google doc viewer open source 2. does google reader allow docs to be offline ?

Comment: I don't think it's open source, but you can check out their [ToS](https://docs.google.com/gview). And no, I don't think it will work offline.